# Error validación imagen en Backend

Tags: nodejs, express, validación, javascript-objeto, backend

A ver si alguien me puede ayudar, se lo agradezco muchisimo. Hasta hace 2 dias mi codigo me funciónaba perfectamente, pero de repente ya no me funciona y no se porque puede ser.

Estoy intentando hacer una validacion de imagenes en backend con cloudinary.
Os paso el codigo, con las dependencias y espero que alguien pueda ver el problema.

```
const router = require('express').Router()
const cloudinary = require('cloudinary')
const fs = require('fs')


cloudinary.config({
    cloud_name: process.env.CLOUD_NAME,
    api_key: process.env.CLOUD_API_KEY,
    api_secret: process.env.CLOUD_API_SECRET
})


router.post('/upload', (req, res) =>{
    try {
        if(!req.files || Object.keys(req.files).length === 0)
            return res.status(400).json({message: 'No hay imagen para subir'})
        
        const file = req.files.file;

        if(file.size > 1024*1024) {
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({message: "Imagen demasiado grande!"})
        }

        if(file.mimetype !== 'image/jpeg' && file.mimetype !== 'image/png'){
            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)
            return res.status(400).json({message: "Formato incorrecto! "})
        }

        cloudinary.v2.uploader.upload(file.tempFilePath, {folder: "ecommerce"}, async(err, result)=>{
            if(err) throw err;

            removeTmp(file.tempFilePath)

           return res.json({public_id: result.public_id, url: result.secure_url})
        })


    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({msg: err.message})
    }
})


router.post('/destroy', (req, res) =>{
    try {
        const {public_id} = req.body;
        if(!public_id) return res.status(400).json({message: 'No hay imagen seleccionada!'})

        cloudinary.v2.uploader.destroy(public_id, async(err, result) =>{
            if(err) throw err;

            res.json({msg: "Imagen borrada"})
        })

    } catch (err) {
        return res.status(500).json({message: err.message})
    }
    
})


const removeTmp = (path) =>{
    fs.unlink(path, err=>{
        if(err) throw err;
    })
}

module.exports = router
```

El mensaje que me sale por postman al intentar subir la imagen es el siguiente :  "msg": "Cannot read property 'size' of undefined" , he comentando el codigo y haciendo console.log y el codigo se me rompe en las validaciones de tamaño y formato de imagen, luego que no me reconoce tempFilePath. Al contrario,en la ruta /destroy , me funciona todo perfectamente.

En cuanto en el archivo server.js tengo esta dependencia instalada :

```
const fileUpload = require("express-fileupload")
const path = require('path')

app.use(fileUpload({
    useTempFiles:true
}))
```

Espero que alguien me pueda ayudar!
Muchas gracias de antemano :)

Comment: verifica en postman que el atributo para subir el archivo se llame _file_

Comment: Lo he verificado y es ese :( . No se porque no me reconoce las propiedades del atributo, llevo días dando vueltas y no encuentro el fallo.

Comment: ¿Podrías mostrar una captura de cómo estás haciendo la petición desde postman y hacer un `console.log()` de `req.files`? Esto para ver como están llegando los datos a tu aplicación, parece ser que si hay contenido en files pero el problema es cuando seleccionas a `file`.

Comment: Gracias a @ricardo-dlc y JackNavaRow , ya pude arreglar el problema. Fue por un despiste mio, al pasar los datos en el postman, no le pasaba bien el atributo. Muchas gracias a los 2 por vuestras respuestas, me ayudar revisar mejor mi codigo. P.D: soy principiante 